# How to assign dynamic colors to the css-border of an image?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

At the moment it changes the background color of the slider component. How can I assign the dynamic color to other objects like the border of an image?

where I want the dynamic colors

```
 <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
      <ion-img [src]="item.src"></ion-img>
    </ion-thumbnail>
```

The color of that border should change depending on the value in ion-range

```
ion-thumbnail{
          border: 2px solid #ffffff;
        }
```

current working code

```
<ion-range [(ngModel)]="value" color="white" [style.background]="getSliderBgColor(value)">
```

Comment: Hi, do you mean changing the border color with a variable or a boolean condition?

Comment: with a variable condition

Comment: Ok. writing in a jiffy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can change the color of your border dynamically in different ways, this works perfectly.

```
<ion-thumbnail slot="start" [style.border-color]="condition ? '#fff' : '#040404'">
      <ion-img [src]="item.src"></ion-img>
</ion-thumbnail>
```

You may also choose to have different css classes for the various colors like this:

```
.white {
      border-color: #fff !important
 }
.blue {
      border-color: blue !important
 }
.black {
      border-color: #000000 !important
 }
```

then in your code you can write this

```
<ion-thumbnail slot="start" [ngClass]="{'white' : 
condition === true, 'blue': bluecondition === true, 'black': blackcondition === true}">
  <ion-img [src]="item.src"></ion-img>
</ion-thumbnail>
```

in this case one should be true in order not to complicate thing, but feel free to move around it.
You could also do this

```
<ion-thumbnail slot="start" [ngClass]="condition? 'white' : 'blue'">
  <ion-img [src]="item.src"></ion-img>
</ion-thumbnail>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Dynamic CSS Border Color

If you're using a framework like Vue and you are receiving your data from a database that contains stuff like the colors etc, you could either have specific classes but that gets tedious...

I recently found that you could pass a css variable to your html as a style property and then use that variable in your css...

*Of course, this needs to be edited to change the below red to a variable of your choosing, this is just the concept.*

```
<style>
    .myDiv {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        border: 1px solid var(--borderColor);
    }
</style>
<div class="myDiv" style="'--borderColor: red;'>Some block</div>
```

From here, you would use Javascript to either change the value of your css variable with the below

```
const root = document.querySelector(':root');
root.style.setProperty('--borderColor', 'blue');
```

Or in Vue logic simply dynamically change the value with something like this

```
<div class="myDiv" :style="'--borderColor: ' + backgroundVariable + ';'">
    Some Block
</div>
```